# VBA PPT referencing a table

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, presentation

I am writing a macro inside Excel that takes values from the worksheet and edits a presentation. 
I am having trouble referencing some values inside a table. 
The line that keeps running into errors is...

```
 reportFile.Slides(7).Shapes(3).Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "fill"
```

It keeps running into error '91' I have tried changing the shape id from numbers through 1-20 and it worked for none of them.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That works for me on a table inserted via `Insert >> Table`

Comment: Same as Tim here; it works on a table inserted via Insert >> Table and on one added by clicking the Table icon in a content placeholder.  Are you sure Shape #3 is a table?  Open the presentation, go to slide 7, press tab to cycle through the shapes on the slide.  If the third press doesn't take you to a table, that'd be the problem.

Comment: Its interesting as this still does not work for me. And yeah it is the 3rd shape when I tab. I even tried re inserting the table and yet it throws the same error. I'm at a little bit of a loss! I'm going to try create a dummy file with 1 slide and 1 table and see if I can get it to work for that.

Comment: Ok so creating a dummy file it didn't work either. There must be something else wrong somewhere else so I will work that out. Thank you both for your help.